# Where is the PyGTK event stack?

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, gnome

You can know if the event stack is empty calling the gtk.events_pending() method, but I want to manipulate the pending events and filter it **before the next gtk loop cycle**, this data must be stored somewhere, but where?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control the event loop yourself.  Rather than calling `gtk.main()`, you can use `gtk.main_iteration`.

Your loop could then be:

```
while running:
    #filter events here
    gtk.main_iteration(true)
```

see [here](http://library.gnome.org/devel/pygtk/stable/gtk-functions.html#function-gtk--main-iteration) for more info.

Comment: Without calling gtk.main() pygtk exits execution, does not wait for events, so should I open an endless while?

Comment: Works, a dirty solution but better than nothing. Thanks

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily call this a dirty solution.  gtk.main internally just calls these methods.  You replace gtk.main with your own loop.

Comment: I call it dirty solution because now I need to change a lot of nested GUI loops resulting of a lack of the obvious method gtk.get_event_stack() ... BTW in the endless loop gtk.get_current_event() is returning nothing, how should I filter them? Thanks for your time again.

Comment: Ah you probably can't quite filter them the way you want after I read the API docs again.  What kind of filtering do you want to do?  What kind of events are you hoping to filter

Comment: Thanks SB, I finally found and alternative solution by doing one-to-one event comparisions in the callbacks. GTK loops wins me. See you.